# Error of finding a database size using a SQL query in SQL Server 2008 on Windows 7

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, windows-7

I would like to use a SQL query to find the size of some databases in SQL Server 2008 MS SQL server management studio.

I run the SQL query:

```
 SELECT 
     d.name,
     ROUND (SUM(mf.size) * 8 / 1024, 0) Size_MBs
 FROM 
     sys.master_files mf
 INNER JOIN 
     sys.databases d ON d.database_id = mf.database_id
 WHERE 
     d.database_id > 4 -- Skip system databases
     AND d.name = 'my_database'  -- after removing this, I still cannot find 'my_database' in the results.
 GROUP BY 
     d.name
 ORDER BY 
     d.name
```

`my_database` has been set up on the server but the result show nothing and cannot find it!

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Check that the user you are running as has permission to see the database.  Try logging into SQL Management Studio using the credentials and connection string you are running the query with.

Comment: I ran the sql query from MS SQL server management studio. I can get the database size by right clicking it one by one, But I have too many databases. I want to get the size of these databases by SQL query.